# Joomla 3 JForm remove fieldset

Tags: forms, joomla, fieldset

I'm developing a user profile plugin for Joomla 3 and I need to manipulate forms according to some conditions. More precisely in the `onContentPrepareForm` event I want to remove a full fieldset of fields, but I can't find in the API a method to do that in-a-row.

At the moment, the solution I'm using is to loop over the fieldset and remove fields, but I don't like this solution.

Any other solutions?

Comment: The conditions that you want to handle occur server-side (PHP) or while the user is filling the form?

Comment: Server-Side. I want to be able to remove a fieldset during his loading process according to some conditions.